# Why UTF-8 is used in class file and UTF-16 in in runtime?

Tags: java, encoding

Why `.class` is UTF-8, but runtime `.class` is UTF-16?

[image]

Comment: Why not ? What if the JVM need UTF-16 but the compiled file doesn't ? What is the problem ?

Comment: @AxelH Relax. He just wants to know why would JVM need UTF-16 rather than UTF-8. This is legitimate!

Comment: @AhmadWabbi I didn't say his question was stupid ... I just point some idea...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Java char uses UTF-16?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236364/why-java-char-uses-utf-16)

Answer (score 8):

> Why .class is UTF-8

For classes written for a Western audience, which are usually mostly ASCII, this is the most compact encoding.

> but runtime .class is UTF-16?

At runtime it's quicker to manipulate strings that use a fixed-width encoding ([Why Java char uses UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236364/why-java-char-uses-utf-16)), so UCS-2 was chosen. This is complicated by the change from UCS-2 to UTF-16 making this another variable-width encoding.

As noted in the comments of that question, [JEP 254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) allows for the runtime representation to change to something more space efficient (e.g., Latin-1).

Comment: *At runtime it's quicker to manipulate strings that use a fixed-width encoding* => was the encoding actually fixed-width when it was introduced, or was there already a notion of graphemes requiring multiple code points?

Comment: Sort of; despite UTF-16 supporting variable-width encoding from its first appearance in Unicode 2.0 in 1996 (http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), UTF-16 was effectively fixed-width until Unicode 3.1 in 2001, which was only supported in J2SE 5 (http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/supplementary-142654.html).

Answer (score -1):

Source code can have any encoding, you can also tell the compiler what encoding to use using the [`-encoding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) flag.

The JVM uses UTF-16, and it's specified in the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

> The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the question is about the encoding of the `.class`-file, not the `.java` file.

Answer (score -2):

[`javac` encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html):

> `-encoding` encoding Set the source file encoding name, such as EUC-JP and UTF-8. If `-encoding` is not specified, the platform default
>   converter is used.

[JVM encoding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

> Every instance of the Java virtual machine has a default charset,
>   which may or may not be one of the standard charsets. The default
>   charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically
>   depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying
>   operating system.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; the question is about the encoding of the `.class`-file, not the `.java` file.

Comment: For the first part of question "Why .class is UTF-8" - when you compile java file to get .class file using javac it uses default encoding, when -encoding option not specified. Second part of question "but runtime .class is UTF-16?" on runtime jvm deals with native library and hence UTF-16

Comment: Again, that doesn't answer the question. You keep talking about the source file, the question is about the encoding used in the compiled `class` file, which is always UTF-8, and the Java process using UTF-16 at runtime.